# Convert my data dataframe where each row includes a list of tuples for each sentence

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I want to read a `.dat` file in python, I have tried a different ways to read it and in the end I arrived at this code:

```
datContent = open("..\\data\\train.dat.abs", 'r')
MyList=[]
for line in datContent:
    print(line)
```

Which opens the content in this form:

```
1   Should  O
2   students    O
3   be  O
4   taught  O
5   to  O
6   compete O
7   or  O
8   to  O
9   cooperate   O
10  ?   O

------------------> THIS SHOWS, STARTING OF THE NEXT SENTENCES

1   It  O
2   is  O
3   always  O
4   said    O
5   that    O
6   competition O
7   can O
8   effectively O
9   promote O
10  the O
11  development O
12  of  O
13  economy O
14  .   O
```

But what I want to extract the first and second column as a list of tuples:

```
[(Should, O), (students,O), (be,O), (taught O), (to,O), (compete,O), (or,O), (to,O), (cooperate,O), (?  O)]
```

Each sentence (sentences has been signed by space in the raw format) is one row of a data frame. I have tried the split.
I have completed that using:

```
datContent = open("..\\data\\train.dat.abs", 'r', encoding='utf-8' )
MyList=[]
for line in datContent:
    a=line.split()
    print(a)
```

The result is so:

```
['1', 'Should', 'O']
['2', 'students', 'O']
['3', 'be', 'O']
['4', 'taught', 'O']
['5', 'to', 'O']
['6', 'compete', 'O']
['7', 'or', 'O']
['8', 'to', 'O']
['9', 'cooperate', 'O']
['10', '?', 'O']
[]
['1', 'It', 'O']
['2', 'is', 'O']
['3', 'always', 'O']
['4', 'said', 'O']
['5', 'that', 'O']
['6', 'competition', 'O']
['7', 'can', 'O']
['8', 'effectively', 'O']
['9', 'promote', 'O']
['10', 'the', 'O']
['11', 'development', 'O']
['12', 'of', 'O']
['13', 'economy', 'O']
['14', '.', 'O']
```

As I told you I want to save:

```
[(Should, O), (students,O), (be,O), (taught O), (to,O), (compete,O), (or,O), (to,O), (cooperate,O), (?  O)]
```

as one row of data frame (basically item 2, 3 of each list above ) and as you  see `[]` separate the sent

df

```
row 1= [(Should, O), (students,O), (be,O), (taught  O), (to,O), (compete,O), (or,O), (to,O), (cooperate,O), (?  O)]
row 2= ...
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PFA8Dw/1) for more.

```
#form: abc['row1'], abc['row2'] ...
def getRowContainer(data):
    rowContainer={}
    rowData=[]
    rowCount=1
    dataSet=re.findall(r'(?:^\d{1,14}\s+([a-zA-Z0-9?!.,]{1,20})\s+([^\s]+))|^-{1,20}>',data,flags=re.MULTILINE)
    for item in (dataSet):
        if item[0]=='':
            rowCount+=1
            rowData=[]
            continue
        rowData.append(item)
        rowContainer[f'row{rowCount}']=rowData
    return rowContainer

rows=getRowContainer(data)

for x in range(1,len(rows)+1):
    print (f'row {x}')
    print (rows[f'row{x}'])
```

I take a screenshot of your input data like this:

```
data='''
1   Should  O
2   students    O
3   be  O
4   taught  O
5   to  O
6   compete O
7   or  O
8   to  O
9   cooperate   O
10  ?   O

------------------> THIS SHOWS, STARTING OF THE NEXT SENTENCES

1   It  O
2   is  O
3   always  O
4   said    O
5   that    O
6   competition O
7   can O
8   effectively O
9   promote O
10  the O
11  development O
12  of  O
13  economy O
14  .   O'''
```

The output I get:

```
row 1
[('Should', 'O'), ('students', 'O'), ('be', 'O'), ('taught', 'O'), ('to', 'O'), ('compete', 'O'), ('or', 'O'), ('to', 'O'), ('cooperate', 'O'), ('?', 'O')]
row 2
[('It', 'O'), ('is', 'O'), ('always', 'O'), ('said', 'O'), ('that', 'O'), ('competition', 'O'), ('can', 'O'), ('effectively', 'O'), ('promote', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), ('development', 'O'), ('of', 'O'), ('economy', 'O'), ('.', 'O')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, the solution is to separate each row in a temporay list with the required data list, and then append each temoporary list into MyList, and finally, forming the DataFrame, as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

datContent = open("..\\data\\train.dat.abs", 'r', encoding='utf-8' )

MyList = []
tmp_list = []

for line in datContent:
    a = line.split()
    if len(a) == 0: # space between sentences
        MyList.append(tmp_list)
        tmp_list = []
        continue
    tmp_list.append((a[1], a[2]))

if len(tmp_list) > 0: # to append the last sentence if not space.
    MyList.append(tmp_list)

df = pd.DataFrame({'sentence': MyList})

print(df)
```